# "Output file stream not open": Error while running SE for X86 using gem5

Tags: gem5

I'm trying to run a SE simulation for x86 platform. Whenever I run the sample command on the website, but it doesn't work

The error log is as follows:

```
gem5.opt: build/X86/base/output.cc:93: OutputFile<StreamType>::OutputFile(const OutputDirectory&, const string&, std::ios_base::openmode, bool) [with StreamType = std::basic_ofstream<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]: Assertion `_fstream->is_open()' failed.
Program aborted at tick 0
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x15)[0x16d8065]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x39)[0x16e8989]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x390200f7e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35)[0x3901832495]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x175)[0x3901833c75]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x390182b60e]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__assert_perror_fail+0x0)[0x390182b6d0]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN15OutputDirectory4openERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESt13_Ios_Openmodebb+0x281)[0xa8ed01]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_ZN5Stats8initTextERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb+0x3f)[0xaaef9f]
build/X86/gem5.opt[0x16bdde0]
build/X86/gem5.opt[0x99f9e1]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x7cf3)[0x180e6e3]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89c)[0x180ff6c]
build/X86/gem5.opt[0x188502e]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyObject_Call+0x3a)[0x177e29a]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xe76)[0x1807866]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89c)[0x180ff6c]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6318)[0x180cd08]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x641a)[0x180ce0a]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89c)[0x180ff6c]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6318)[0x180cd08]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89c)[0x180ff6c]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyEval_EvalCode+0x19)[0x1810059]
build/X86/gem5.opt(PyRun_StringFlags+0xf5)[0x1837db5]
build/X86/gem5.opt(_Z6m5MainiPPc+0x5f)[0x16e74bf]
build/X86/gem5.opt(main+0x38)[0x7410d8]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x390181ed1d]
build/X86/gem5.opt[0x766d31]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
Abort
```

Comment: Hi Kartick, please provide: your gem5 git SHA version, a description of your content and test if it happens on a hello world / some onther minimal content. Here is [a working setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/c98d93f7f7c14888b50172d9f2a1752fdd490850#gem5-syscall-emulation-mode).

Comment: Hi, as it turns out, I didn't have permissions to modify the m5out folder in the directory. Worked when I tried to output the simulation in another folder.

Thanks! :D

Comment: Ha! Consider answering your own question with that comment.